# How to build an advanced link in draw.io

Tags: draw.io

I am looking for how you can build a link in draw io, so that when you click first, it hides a layer and then opens a different page of the same draw io document.

so far i tried this:

```
data:action/json,{"actions":[{"toggle": {"cells": ["SvuciECQg7tZUCU10AH1-3"]}},{"open": "data:page/id,IZEQzf0yfGXm-2QJ5-Q8"}]}
```

But it seems that the Toggle is executed after the Open, and I need the Toggle to be first and then the Open.

I even tried to do an Open of the same page I'm on, do the Toggle, and then do the Open of page 2, but it didn't work. I would appreciate if anyone knows how to do this, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty old, you've probably figured it out or given up by now.  In case you haven't:
If you want to Hide a layer, just Hide the layer.  This did exactly what you're describing: (I've inserted your IDs)

```
data:action/json,{"actions":[{"hide":{"cells":["SvuciECQg7tZUCU10AH1-3"]}},{"open":"data:page/id,IZEQzf0yfGXm-2QJ5-Q8"}]}
```

If you need to toggle the layer back on, you'll need to Show it again.  The code you have works, it's kindof unexpected not knowing if the layer is showing or hidden at the start.

**Unless the layer you want to show/hide is on the different page.**
You won't be able to interact with objects on a page that's not in scope.  In that case, you probably want to hide the layer by default.  That way, when you Open the second page, the layer is already hidden.